# Any equipment that allows the viewing of a laser beams that would not be very noticeable with the naked eye?

Tags: visible-light, laser

Would equipment such as infrared googles, nightvision, or other be able to display the path of a laser beam in a situation where the laser beam is not visible with the naked eye?

Or maybe have the laser pulse at a certain frequency to make it 'invisible'?

Comment: The question is a bit vague.  A visible light laser passing through dust-free air would be invisible, because there's nothing to scatter it.  An infra-red laser would be invisible because we can't see infra-red.

Comment: Would a laser heat the air in its path? If so, would the laser be visible with infrared equipment when the laser is in a dust-free environment?

Comment: IR goggles and night vision goggles can be used to see laser beams. It all depends on the beam wavelength and the particular goggles.

Comment: And how much dust is in the air to scatter the laser light toward the viewer.

Answer (score 2):

What Simon B says is correct :

> A visible light laser passing through dust-free air would be invisible, because there's nothing to scatter it. An infra-red laser would be invisible because we can't see infra-red.

A light beam is invisible when it passes through pure air. This is true for ordinary (incoherent) light as well as laser (coherent) light, and for visible light as well as IR. You can only see the beam if it is scattered from particles in the air which are approximately the size of the wavelength of the beam. In pure air the particles are molecules on the order of $0.1nm$ in length, far smaller than $400-700nm$ for visible light and $>700nm$ for IR. So there is effectively no scattering of the beam in pure air.

To see a laser beam as it passes through air, you need to introduce larger particles - dust or smoke or aerosol spray - to scatter some of the light from the beam in the direction of your eye. Dust particles tend to get trapped in the beam and can remain there for a few minutes. The light passing through the dust or smoke particles exerts a small force towards the most intense region of the beam.

Household dust is larger than visible wavelengths $(500nm)$ so there will be more scattering of an IR beam $(\lambda > 700nm)$ from dust or smoke or mist, which could be seen with IR goggles. However, air quality in a laser laboratory is usually required to be much better than in a house or office.

> Would a laser heat the air in its path? If so, would the laser be visible with infrared equipment when the laser is in a dust-free environment?

No, the laser beam does not have much effect in heating the air which it passes through. So you would not be able to see a "hot" beam using IR goggles.

Laser beams are usually viewed when they scatter from rough (matt) surfaces which are placed in the beam. IR beams are viewed using phosphorescent cards which convert IR into visible light.

Comment: What Simon B said is actually not correct and neglects Rayleigh scattering, in which light can be (and is) scattered from individual atoms and molecules, which can be much, much smaller than the wavelength of the incident light. This occurs for any dielectric medium, but is quite a weak effect and is also very strongly wavelength-dependent with short-wavelength radiation being scattered more strongly and through steeper angles. With a high-power, short-wavelength laser in a completely dust-free lab, you would be able to see the laser beam passing through air.